# AdWords Ad performance report: will recalculation happen?

Tags: report, google-ads-api

Am trying to run some program to process some Adwords ad performance report using API 201710. I am curious in the cases where if I downloaded an ad performance report for yesterday, will the data be different if I download it a couple of days from now? Since some more user activities might have happened from the day I first download the report. And if the data will change, what is the max date range for such recalculation? (like after 7 days the data will stay the same)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- AdWords reports are delayed by a few hours or for some metrics such as impression share slightly longer
- If you are using AdWords conversion tracker to track your conversions depending on the [conversion window](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3123169) these metrics can change. If you are on a 30 day conversion window for example and 10 days ago your campaign drove 10 conversions, then these users make 40 additional conversions over the next 20 days. The same day would now show 50 conversions as opposed to 10 as they were attributed to the click which generated the sale
- Click fraud will be another reason for seeing difference in numbers. If you download a report for yesterday you may see 200 clicks which cost £50. Then if you generate this report in 2 weeks times you may see 195 clicks with a cost of £45. Basically Google click fraud process has identified fraudulent clicks and subtracted the clicks from the total and not charged for these clicks. I am not too sure up until how long Google will check for click fraud, but I recommend downloading the last 30 days data daily and simply overwriting your dataset. In this case you would need a primary key, My common approach to creating an AdWords primary key is to use the date and concatenate all the segments and any IDs i.e. date+campaign_id+device+network. I would not use campaign names as these can be changed by the user.
- [Click here for](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2544985?hl=en-GB) a good article from Google which probably explains it better I did!

Comment: Thank you for the info! Will take a look.